# Inconsistent page count of a PDF document

Tags: pdf, vb6

I'm trying to get the number of pages in the PDF document. Some of my PDFs are created in Word (saved as PDF), some of them are Xeroxed into the directory (not sure if this matters).

After hours of research I've come to find out that this is easier said than done. **The page count rarely comes back giving me the correct number of pages**, even though most PDF's do in fact have `/Count` inside the Binary Code.

For example I've used the following code; it is supposed to open the document in Binary Mode, look for `/Count` or `/N` and get the number next to it which is supposed to give me the page count.

```
Public Sub pagecount(sfilename As String)
    On Error GoTo a
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim pos, pos1 As Integer
    pos = 0
    pos1 = 0
    c = 0
    ' Get an available file number from the system
    nFileNum = FreeFile
    'OPEN the PDF file in Binary mode
    Open sfilename For Binary Lock Read Write As #nFileNum
    ' Get the data from the file
    Do Until EOF(nFileNum)
    Input #1, s
    c = c + 1
    If c <= 10 Then
        pos = InStr(s, "/N")
    End If
    pos1 = InStr(s, "/count")
       If pos > 0 Or pos1 > 0 Then
            Close #nFileNum
            s = Trim(Mid(s, pos, 10))
            s = Replace(s, "/N", "")
            s = Replace(s, "/count", "")
            s = Replace(s, " ", "")
            s = Replace(s, "/", "")
            For i = 65 To 125
                    s = Replace(s, Chr(i), "")
            Next
            pages = Val(Trim(s))
            If pages < 0 Then
                pages = 1
            End If
            Close #nFileNum
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'imp only 1000 lines searches
        If c >= 1000 Then
             GoTo a
        End If
     Loop
       Close #nFileNum
       Exit Sub
   a:
       Close #nFileNum
       pages = 1
       Exit Sub
End Sub
```

However, most of the time, it defaults to pages = 1 (under a:). 
I've also updated this to 10000 to be sure that it hits the `/Count` line, yet it still does not give me the correct count.

```
If c >= 10000 Then
         GoTo a
End If
```

I also came across this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/visualbasic/comments/29n2xa/getting_pdf_page_count/)

Is there another way to do this, something I can utilize in my app?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Background:

This is for a legacy vb6 app where I'm attempting to let the user manipulate the PDF files. I added a ListBox that displays all PDF documents in a particular directory. When user double clicks on any one of the files, i display it in a WebBrowser component inside my application.

EDIT: Image containing the BinaryMode line Count for 3 different documents:
[image]

I double checked the page count, and /Count displays the correct page count for each of the three documents.

Comment: Unless your PDFs are created by the same generator, you cannot determine the correct page number without honoring the pdf structure, i.e. parsing the file from its back, locating the root of the **Pages** tree via file trailer and cross references, and analyzing that root object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions have limits, but I prefer to use them for searching for strings and I think this would be a good place to use one. You may want to play with the pattern because I did this relatively quickly with only a little testing.

Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 to your project. Then you can try the sample code below.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim oRegEx As RegExp
    Dim fHndl As Integer
    Dim sContents As String
    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection

    On Error GoTo ErrCommand1_Click

    'Open and read in the file
    fHndl = FreeFile
    Open some pdf file For Binary Access Read As fHndl
    sContents = String(LOF(fHndl), vbNull)
    Get #fHndl, 1, sContents
    Close #fHndl    'We have the file contents so close it
    fHndl = 0

    'Instantiate and configure the RegEx
    Set oRegEx = New RegExp
    oRegEx.Global = True
    oRegEx.Pattern = "((?:/Count )(\d+))"
    Set oMatches = oRegEx.Execute(sContents)

    'Look for a match
    If oMatches.Count > 0 Then
       If oMatches(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
           MsgBox CStr(oMatches(0).SubMatches(0)) & " Pages"
       End If
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrCommand1_Click:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description
    If Not oRegEx Is Nothing Then Set oRegEx = Nothing
    If Not oMatches Is Nothing Then Set oMatches = Nothing

End Sub
```

An explanation of the RegEx pattern:
`()` creates a group
`?:` inside the parenthesis makes the group non-capturing
`<</Linearized` is a literal string
`.*` greedy quantifier, match any character 0 or more times
`/N` literal string
`\d+` greedy qualtifier, match digits 1 or more times
`>>` literal string

Comment: Not every pdf is linearized. And not every pdf with a **Linearized** dictionary still is linearized. Thus, your choice may help if the pdfs are from some homogeneous source, for generic pdfs it will fail more often than not.

Comment: I tried it with 3 different documents and didn't get a page number for either one of them

Comment: @mkl I opened the pdf documents I had on hand in notepad++ and developed the regex pattern from that. The technique works, but the pattern may well need to be adjusted, or even 2 or more patterns tried until a match is found. Do you have a more generic pattern? The key is matching the line with the page number.

Comment: @jac Due to the nature of the PDF format there are very many ways to encode the number of pages, including some where the position you find your literal strings only contains a reference to somewhere else in the PDF to retrieve the value. Effectively you cannot hope for a generic pattern for all PDFs. If on the other hand you have a limited number of PDF generators, finding some pattern(s) to extract the page count from their creations is feasible. (Unless compressed object streams are used, that is...)

Comment: @Koosh If you have to deal with PDFs from a single PDF generator (or a very few of them) only, you might want to share examples for which jac or others can derive page number extraction functions.

Comment: Each document I have opened used the keyword /count 1    and then shows the correct page number. For some reason the functcion does not see it.

Comment: @Koosh Can you add the complete line that contains the page count to your question?

Comment: @Koosh I've made a change based on the images above. I'm not comfortable with how simple the pattern is since I can't see the rest of the document I don't know if there is a potential for matches where there is no page count. I have not updated the pattern explanation. Try it out though and let me know.